# Selecting children from families having exactly 2 children or exactly 1 child

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

Ten children are to be selected for a course from 52 families of a village.  Of these 52 families, 32 familes have 2 children each and 20 have one child.  Five children to be selected from 5 different families having two children each and remaining 5 from 5 ifferent families having exactly one child.  In how many ways can 10 children be selected ?

---

**My attempt:-**

Ways of selecting 5 families from 32 families having 2 children each and then selecting 1 child out of the two from each family

${32 \choose 5}*2^5$

Ways of selecting 5 families from the the 20 families having exactly one child

${20 \choose 5}$

Total ways of selecting 10 children = ${32 \choose 5}*2^5 * {20 \choose 5}$

---

however as per official answer it is $25*{20 \choose 5}*{20 \choose 5}$

Have I done the $2^5$ step incorrectly ?

Comment: Are you sure that the book answer pertains to the question you have shown ? For the question you have shown, your answer is correct.

Comment: I think that the comment of @trueblueanil nails it.  Personally, I tried to *reverse-engineer* some variation of the posted problem, where the correct answer would be $~\displaystyle 25 \times \binom{20}{5} \times \binom{20}{5}.~$  I can't find any *moderate* alteration of the problem's constraints that would explain the *official* answer.